# Acer Aspire R3-131T R11 with LTSP 14.04 starts with black screen

Tags: 14.04, boot, xorg, acer, ltsp

I'm having trouble with an Acer R11 laptop (client). It boots over Lan getting its disk image from an 14.04 LTSP Server. After the initial Acer Splash-DHCP-TFTP sequence a console is shortly visible, followed by the Acer Splash (probably still in video memory) and then the screen turns black with backlight on.

The LTSP 14.04 install is tested and works with an Asus Eee T101MT (including Touchscreen).
Important to know the same Acer R11: Live USB 14.04 works fine (with Touchscreen), and LTSP 12.04 as a client also works (but without Touchscreen).

I am desperately trying to solve this. I tried kernel parameters (nomodeset, noapic...)

I can reach the client over ssh.

```
    less /var/log/Xorg.7.log | grep EE
[   289.888] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   289.889] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[   289.889] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   289.890] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   289.890] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   289.890] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[   289.996] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

I can even startx over ssh and then start an xterm on the server.

When I try to get a working xorg.conf with `Xorg -configure` the error I get is `Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.`

```
root@AspireR11-01:~# Xorg -configure
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-76-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux AspireR11-01 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: ro initrd=initrd.img-3.13.0-74-generic init=/sbin/init-ltsp quiet splash root=/dev/nbd0 BOOT_IMAGE=vmlinuz-3.13.0-74-generic BOOTIF=01-30-65-ec-85-03-3b 
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:29PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Feb 19 17:03:29 2016
List of video drivers:
        ati
        cirrus
        vmware
        intel
        mach64
        mga
        modesetting
        neomagic
        nouveau
        openchrome
        qxl
        r128
        radeon
        s3
        savage
        siliconmotion
        sis
        sisusb
        spiceqxl
        tdfx
        trident
        vesa
        fbdev
(++) Using config file: "/root/xorg.conf.new"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

This created is the xorg.conf.new

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
        Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "NoAccel"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"               # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"                 # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                       # <str>
        #Option     "ColorKey"                  # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"                  # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                    # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"               # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"              # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"               # [<bool>]
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Aces Aspire R11
The solution was to install a newer kernel

```
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your input, alas, it didn't help.

Comment: After trying it the clients came up with a new  error:  overlayfs missing 'workdir' (there seem to be issues with wily and overlayfs->overlay). They booted into busybox...  I decided to start over again and finally it turned out that creating an ` ltsp-build- image --arch i386 `  (and setting the dhcpd.conf to serve the i386 image) worked out of the box (3.19.0-51-generic) the interesting bit is that the amd64 image had only kernel 3.13.0-79 - so I assume your answer is correct!